# que utilizar para generar pdf con c#

Tags: c#, pdf

disculpen, necesito generar el formato de un calendario maya con c#, esta formado por imágenes y no se que puedo utilizar para hacerlo, no es un reporte de base de datos, son 10 imágenes que necesito imprimir. es algo un formato como este http://maya.nmai.si.edu/sites/all/themes/mayatime/img/calendar-system/es/9.jpg

Comment: pero las imagenes estas prediseñadas (quizas en archivos de imagenes) y solo tienes que ubicarlas en el pdf ?

Comment: si, ya tengo todas las imagenes, ahora me falta imprimirlas en pdf, y no se que puedo utilizar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Una librerias ampliamente usada para generar pdf en .net es [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/)

[iTextSharp - Working with images](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images)

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfpath + "/Images.pdf", FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();

doc.Add(new Paragraph("GIF"));

Image gif = Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/nombreimagen.gif");
doc.Add(gif);
```

Es bastante simple de entender el código, solo agregas una imagen en el parrafo del pdf. En el artículo encontraras mas ejemplo con otros formatos de imagen.

Answer (score 0):

> iTextSharp

es un librería con una cantidad impresionante de funciones y muy fácil de utilizar.
Te recomiendo utilizarla, ya que podrás personalizar el documento de la manera que desees.

Acá podrás encontrar un tutorial básico de desarrollo. -- > [Creando archivo PDF con iTextSharp](http://desarrolladores.me/2014/01/c-creando-archivos-pdf-con-itextsharp/)

Así mismo desde ahí podrás descargar las librerías necesarias.

¡Mucha Suerte! :D

Comment: Si bien podrías estar respondiendo a la pregunta, la información está en un enlace externo que podría dejar de estar disponible en un futuro. ¿Podrías agregar las partes relevantes en tu respuesta, dejando el enlace como fuente o para ver mayor información?